# Dynamic memory allocation seems instant in debug but gradual in release mode

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-allocation

I have a large dynamically allocated array (C++, MSVC110), and I am initializing it like this:

```
try {
    size_t arrayLength = 1 << 28;
    data = new int[arrayLength];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        data[i] = rand();
    }
}
catch (std::bad_alloc&) { /* Report error. */ }
```

Everything was fine before I tried to allocate more than system's actual RAM, like 10 GB. I was expecting to catch a `bad_alloc` exception, but the system (Win7) started to swap as crazy, etc.. you know what I am talking about.

Then I examined the situation in my task manager and noticed interesting thing, in debug mode the allocation was instant, but in release, it was gradual.

Debug mode:

[image: Debug mode allocation graph]

Release mode:

[image: Release mode allocation graph]

What is causing it? Could this have any negative impact on performance? Have I done something wrong? Is OS causing this? Or C++ allocator?

I would actually prefer to get an exception if there is not enough memory rather than go to endless swapping loop. Is there any way how to achieve it in C++?

I know that one solution might be turn off swapping in Windows, but that would solve the problem only for me.

Comment: I think this is caused by the DEBUG C-standard library code to place certain debug info into any allocated memory, thereby immediately accessing it and causing it to become paged-in. In release, you probably gradually page-in the memory, depending on how you access/use it.

Comment: I'm agree with MicroVirus. Check [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c9535/Inside-CRT-Debug-Heap-Management.htm) for more information about the windows debug heap metadata.

Comment: @MicroVirus please post your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the memory allocator is doing some chaining in debug mode to allow better detection of memory handling errors. It will access every allocated block to write a few bytes in each, thus forcing the system to commit all pages allocated quickly.

In release mode, it is your code that does the linear filling of the block, thus commiting one page at a time.

As for limiting the amount of memory, well you have system calls to let you know about available resources. [These, for instance, in Windows environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Having a system call fail if memory sawp is required would make no sense, since the amount of available memory changes constantly due to circumstances a given program cannot control (like other applications being started).

There are possibilities to make some memory blocks non-swappable (i.e. locked in RAM), but that kind of usage is usually limited to system layers like drivers.

It is up to you to detect available memory and enforce an allocation limit.

Note that it is a dangerous game; since you are usually not running alone on the computer, and there is no telling if another application will be launched later and consume more memory.

If swap is a killer for your application, you should consider taking safety margins (i.e. try to leave something like 500Mb or 1 Gb of RAM available to the system)

Comment: I believe the new memory block is filled with 0xCDCDCDCD to signify that it is uninitialized heap memory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations

Comment: @drescherjm Yes it is, but before that I suspect the allocator does other accesses, or else you should observe the same result as the release version.

Comment: Release does not fill the heap.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, but the OP's example does

Comment: I see.. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @drescherjm No problem. Your points are valid, and a clarification was welcome.

Comment: The only thing that surprises me is that the debug version can fill the memory so fast and my code is much slower. Maybe the the random generator (std::mt199370 is slowing things down. Also, I am accessing the memory by chars so it slows down the iteration even further.